# Strange straight line in flutter fl_chart

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

I have a line chart that builds by a combination of several data. But the curve draws some strange straight lines on some areas.

How can i delete this line?

The problem is i think not related to the data because icannot touch with cursor to this straight line. I think curve automatically draws something like regression line, but icouldn't remove it.

Thank you.

[image]

Another example

[image]

[image]

if i chose dot data as true, you can see that there is no data point on these straight lines.
[image]

Comment: can you show us on which data graph is drawn??

Comment: Since the data is big print cannot show all of the datas to console. Only some portion. I put some of the data to the question area.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. For those who has the same issue, the data of the curve should be sorted. If your data is map, just turn the map to sorted with collection package with the following code;

```
data = SplayTreeMap();
```

That's it.